# What hydrolyses aspirin within the digestive tract and blood stream?

Tags: pharmacology, aspirin

I have had some further thoughts after my previous question [regarding the **buccal delivery** of medication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/345/why-would-diffusion-be-faster-across-a-non-specialised-tissue).  The active compound in aspirin (*acetylsalicylic acid* or systematically 2-Acetoxybenzoic acid)  is salicylic acid (2-hydroxybenzoic acid).

I understand that the hydrolysis reaction occurs as follows *within the stomach* - therefore in the body it is an *acid* hydrolysis:

[image: Hydrolysis of aspirin]

*N.B. The H<sub>2</sub>O is not shown in the diagram.*

However having done this experimentally I know that in the lab to ensure a decent yield of salicylic acid I had to ***reflux* the solution for several hours**.  Yet the onset of action of aspirin tablets is much faster than this.  To me this suggests some enzymatic activity, but I have no idea which enzyme this is likely to be.

To follow on directly from my previous question, if the aspirin is absorbed directly into the bloodstream bypassing the stomach then what causes the hydrolysis in the blood stream and is it the same factor that increases the rate of hydrolysis *in* the stomach if the medication were to be taken orally?

Comment: As a side question, how are you doing all this lab work as an A-level student? V. impressive!

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm lucky enough to be on a really obscure chemistry exam board - OCR Salters.  It's the most practically based since Nuffield bit the dust. We have to do an extended lab project over a few months, which is a great opportunity for us!

Answer (score 6):

[Acetylsalicylate deacetylase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acetylsalicylate_deacetylase) is the enzyme responsible for this reaction.

> Precisely, the present investigation reveals that the hydrolysis of aspirin in liver, kidney and probably other tissues of
>   rats is catalyzed by two highly substrate specific microsomal
>   esterases, ASA esterase I and II active at acidic and slightly
>   alkaline pH, respectively. The findings that ASA esterases have
>   distinct organ distribution pattern and display responses to
>   various inhibitors/activators that are different in many respects
>   from those exhibited by cholinesterase and nonspecific carboxylesterase suggest that the latter esterases probably do not play
>   a significant role in the hydrolysis of aspirin.
>
> From:
>   *Ali B, Kaur S (1983) Mammalian tissue acetylsalicylic acid esterase(s): identification, distribution and discrimination from other esterases. J Pharmacol Exp Ther,226,589-594*

Comment: That's an interesting one - according to [the handbook of enzymes](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=F-0y0w33FlQC&pg=PA355&lpg=PA357&dq=Acetylsalicylate+deacetylase&source=bl&ots=P5S6t3IRl4&sig=Uo9cKC42oVaiUaarjt60RZw6ly0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mko2T_uWBaXV0QX76tzCAg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Acetylsalicylate%20deacetylase&f=false) notably page 357, the enzyme doesn't seem adapted for use in the human stomach.  This suggests that it is active elsewhere - a website suggested the liver. Does anyone know if this is the case (as it would prove an answer to how the hydrolysis happens in the bloodstream)?

Comment: @RoryM See my update with a quote from the article.  Much of the drug metabolism that the body does happens in the liver anyway, after all these are just safe dosages of "toxins" that we take for our health!

Comment: However in [Alexander's Answer to the linked question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/376/69) he states one advantage of buccal delivery as the bypassing of the liver.  As this method supposedly gives faster delivery of the medication there must be another factor at play somewhere =)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_pass_effect.  First pass effect is just that, the reduction in the amount of absorption when the drug is first metabolized.  One's blood volume makes many more subsequent passes through your liver.  The article also notes the kidney as a location of the enzyme, which is just as likely to revisit the same blood volume.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting, but the 1st pass effect is one that *reduces* the potency of drugs.  The enzyme you mentioned above that hydrolyses aspirin into salicylic acid would be *increasing* potency as salicylic acid is the active ingredient, therefore the first-pass effect does not apply?

Comment: I don't want to go too far out on a limb here, because I don't know for sure, but there are probably non-specific enzymes that metabolize the ASA directly in first-pass, either by oxidation (e.g., the p450s) or conjugation (the various transferases) which render it inert.  The liver is a complicated machine, and I regret that I don't remember more about first pass metabolism.

Comment: You may want to see if Alexander wants to take a peek at this question, too.

Comment: @TomD I think you misunderstood, Rory was not referring to the pharmacodynamics of aspirin itself, but the pharmacokinetics of the removal of aspirin from the system.

Comment: @RoryM See the answer to my latest [question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/circulation-through-the-liver-in-light-of-drug-metabolism) I think it finally clears this one up.  The sublingual drugs will in fact be carried to the liver via the hepatic artery, just not initially.