# Is sugar absorbed into the bloodstream through the walls of the mouth?

Tags: food, digestion, sugar

If you let a piece of candy melt in your mouth, but did not swallow it, would the sugar be absorbed through the walls of your mouth?

Comment: Welcome to SE kindly read tour page about how to ask question and modify yours accordingly. Your question would be downvoted or closEd  as it shows no effort to answer  and any kind of research.

Comment: @Chemist Answering questions that are not well-researched rather encourages people to post such questions anyways.

Comment: @BryanKrause Answering poorly researched questions isn't to me inherently wrong. The issue is that you cannot tell what the question is. Is this person asking about how digestion works? How sugar is tasted? If sugar can be absorbed directly as well as or instead of absorption in the gut? Is it asking about dissolving sugars? Is it asking about the composition of saliva? There is too much to unpack here to make an answer useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What nutrients can humans absorb in the mouth?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/what-nutrients-can-humans-absorb-in-the-mouth)

Comment: @James, the title of the question says: "Is sugar absorbed _into the bloodstream_ through the walls of the mouth?" so this is clearly about absorption and the topic is very interesting in the context of treatment of hypoglycemia, as I answered.

Comment: @Jan That is a very nice answer! But it doesn't address the question in the context of candy ;). I suggest you edit the question; I think you see the value in this question and how it could be made into a good clear question.

Comment: @James, well, the "candy" in the question was just used as an example. OK, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple sugars such as glucose, fructose and galactose will be absorbed.**

- They are most probably transported by a common carrier, which is why if you present both glucose and galactose, the presence of one will inhibit the absorption rate of the other.
- Uptake rate also seems to partly depend on the concentration of sodium ions in the buccal cavity. This was [identified](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/954358) and [explored](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022354915508484) subsequently.
- It seems that at the cellular level, absorption is not the quickest but there is a lot of vascularization which allows it to enter the bloodstream quickly, regardless.

[image]

**Here's a back-of-the-envelope calculation:** about 10mg is absorbed in 5 minutes when you hold a solution of 3.6g/l in your mouth. A normal gulp volume is around 10ml. That's 36mg of sugar in a mouthful. Result: you can absorb 10mg of sugar from a theoretical maximum of 36mg. In other words, within 5 minutes, you absorb ~30% of all available sugar. That's pretty good, given that a sugar solution is not a more concentrated, solid sugary food!

Worthy to note that **most complex sugars will not be absorbed.** Note that many complex sugars actually won't be uptaken even in rest of the GI tract, like cellulose.

See [other](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7019/what-nutrients-can-humans-absorb-in-the-mouth) [posts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/345/why-would-diffusion-be-faster-across-a-non-specialised-tissue/) already here on the topic.

Comment: @Jan [Of interest.](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3982/are-users-allowed-to-edit-questions-to-better-suit-the-answer-they-can-provide?cb=1)

Comment: Yes, there is sucrase in the mouth, but not human in origin! Bacteria that live in the mouth produce glucansucrase that can break down sucrose.

Answer (score 4):

The absorption of sugar from the mouth is possible and it was successfully tested for treatment of hypoglycemia. In all mentioned studies, they used D-glucose (dextrose), which is a common natural or added sugar in foods and beverages.

**1) [Sublingual sugar administration as an alternative to intravenous dextrose administration to correct hypoglycemia among children in the tropics (Pediatrics, 2005)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16263979):**

> Sixty-nine children with glucose concentrations of < 0.8 g/L were
>   assigned randomly to 1 of 4 methods of administration, 1 with 3
>   different doses of sugar, as follows: oral group (OG) (n = 15): 2.5 g
>   of sugar; sublingual group (SG) (n = 27): 2.5 g of sugar under the
>   tongue, with 3 treatment subgroups, ie, 0.1 g/kg, 0.15 g/kg, and 0.2
>   g/kg; intravenous group (IG) (n = 8): 8 mL of 30% dextrose in a single
>   bolus; water group (n = 11)...**Bioavailabilities were 84% and 38% in
>   the SG [sublingual group] and OG [oral group], respectively. The
>   sublingual administration of sugar proved to be effective among
>   moderately hypoglycemic children.**

**2) [Impact of buccal glucose spray, liquid sugars and dextrose tablets on the evolution of plasma glucose concentration in healthy persons (ResearchGate, 2009)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38030945_Impact_of_buccal_glucose_spray_liquid_sugars_and_dextrose_tablets_on_the_evolution_of_plasma_glucose_concentration_in_healthy_persons):**

> Analysis of regression coefficients after 30 min compared to the
>   control session, demonstrated an increase in PG [plasma glucose] with the sachet of
>   liquid sugars (0.068 mmol/l/min, p = 0.001) which was greater than a
>   single dextrose tablet (0.052 mmol/l/min, p = 0.002), but no
>   significant PG increase was found after buccal glucose spray. **Liquid
>   sugars or dextrose tablets, but not the buccal glucose spray, are
>   effective means to increase PG within 10 minutes after ingestion.**

**3) [Dextrose gel for neonatal hypoglycaemia (the Sugar Babies Study): a randomised, double-blind, placebo-controlled trial (The Lancet, 2013)](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(13)61645-1/fulltext):**

> Our findings show that treatment with 40% dextrose gel is more
>   effective than feeding alone for reversal of neonatal hypoglycaemia in
>   at-risk late preterm and term babies in the first 48 h after
>   birth....**Our study is the first report in babies showing that buccal
>   dextrose gel is a safe effective treatment for management of
>   hypoglycaemia.**

**4) [Sublingual sugar for infant hypoglycaemia (The Lancet, 2014)](https://www.thelancet.com/pdfs/journals/lancet/PIIS0140-6736(14)60601-2.pdf)**

> **We showed that sublingual absorption was faster than the oral route.**
>   An increase of 2 mmol/L in blood glucose concentration was achieved in
>   10 min, and 64% of children had a blood glucose concentration of more
>   than 3·3 mmol/L after 20 min.

**5) [First aid glucose administration routes for symptomatic hypoglycaemia (Cochrane, 2019)](https://www.cochrane.org/CD013283/ENDOC_first-aid-glucose-administration-routes-symptomatic-hypoglycaemia):**

> **Providing sugar under the tongue (sublingual) resulted in a greater rise in blood glucose after 20 minutes than giving the sugar orally,**
>   but this was in a specific setting including children with
>   hypoglycaemia and symptoms of concomitant malaria or respiratory tract
>   infection. On the other hand, giving glucose by the buccal mucosa
>   route resulted in a lower plasma glucose concentration than with the
>   oral route. For dextrose gel (where uptake of the glucose occurs
>   through a combination of oral swallowing and via the buccal mucosa),
>   no clear benefit was shown compared to oral glucose administration
>   (glucose tablets or glucose solutions).

**Important:** Currently, buccal glucose is not recommended to treat hypoglycemia, except in uncooperative children who refuse to swallow glucose ([International Liaison Committee on Resuscitation, 2019](https://costr.ilcor.org/document/methods-of-glucose-administration-in-first-aid-for-hypoglycemia)) .